# Strange growth on a pepper plant

Tags: diseases, peppers, chili

I noticed a strange growth on a Capsicum chinense plant. Based on location I believe, it is is some sort of deformation of the flower bud (maybe fasciation).

It resembles broccoli florets. No other obvious signs of a disease are visible and only one plant in this location is affected.

What could be the problem?

[image: location of the deformation]

[image: magnification of the deformation]

Comment: Since it's been 8 days, has anything changed? My 'best' guess would be that this could be a [boron deficiency](https://www.greenhousecanada.com/growing-points-more-on-boron-with-peppers-3907/), but then I would expect e.g. leaves to show some sign of that too, even if it wasn't noticeable at first, by now.